# HTTP/S Load Balancing as Caching Reverse Proxy

Tags: caching, nginx, google-compute-engine, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx server installed at my RHEL7 GCE host configured as a caching reverse proxy server, distributing traffic to two non-GCE webservers. I'd like to replace Nginx with native GCE features, which seems to be the HTTP/S Load Balancing features. But the GCE load balancing seems designed to distribute traffic to only other GCE instances. And I don't know whether GCE can cache what it's reverse proxying.

My non-GCE webservers are across a VPN configured with the GCE host as an endpoint. The two webservers are actually listening at the same IP address but different ports. I'd like to access them by https://gce-host.com/this -> https://non-gce-host.com:80 and https://gce-host.com/that -> https://non-gce-host.com:81 .

I'd also like to consider the other Nginx features, like access control.

Is the native GCE featureset a reasonable replacement for the Nginx caching reverse proxy server? Or should I stick with Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP(S) load balancing does not support non-GCE hosts nor ACLs at this point.

If you'd still like to benefit from the global footprint and caching of Google's HTTP(S) frontend infrastructure, you can of course use [Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/) in conjunction with a very lightweight, non-caching reverse proxy.

The benefit here would be that you get caching close to the user - as such, the nginx proxy on GCE does not have to perform caching itself, possibly reducing the necessary machine size as it would only be shuffling bits back and forth to your origin server and performing ACL checks.

Comment: Thanks. You're suggesting using the Nginx on the GCE host as the reverse proxy to the non-GCE origin servers because GCP doesn't support non-GCE origin servers, but not caching in Nginx, and instead using Cloud CDN as the caching layer. Is activating the Cloud CDN on that Nginx config transparent, so all hits on the GCE webserver (Nginx) would be cached by Cloud CDN? No hits directly on the GCE webserver would go around the Cloud CDN cache?

Comment: The answer is: It depends. The caching headers etc. have to be set properly configured of course. Cache misses are explained more [here](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview#fill-and-egress) and the necessary config [here](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching)

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear. I want the direct access (bypass the cache) to the GCE host to be inaccessible to the public Internet, so only by going through the cache is the GCE host accessible. Yes, some of those hits will be cache MISS (ie. new resource on the origin server), but will populate the cache when the request comes through the cache to the GCE host (and then back to the origin server).

Comment: Ah I see. That's quite simple, you can just setup a firewall rule that only allows [130.211.0.0/22](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#troubleshooting)